# Android how would you make this layout in Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I basically want to create a layout like so which has a view at the bottom that you scroll up over the background image.  Which then fades away and allows you to continue scrolling.

Reference:

https://imgur.com/a/FxLqOXK

Answer (score 1):

Another implementation to explore could be done using `LazyColumn` and `stickyHeader` item. Sticky header is an experimental API though and it can change in the future - docs can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists#sticky-headers).

This is the effect of the following composable:

[image: Collapsing toolbar with sticky header]

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun ListWithCollapsingToolbar() {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(Color.Green)
    ) {
        LazyColumn {
            item {
                Box(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(250.dp)
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(60.dp)
                            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
                            .background(
                                Brush.verticalGradient(
                                    listOf(
                                        Color.Transparent,
                                        Color.Gray
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                    )
                }
            }
            stickyHeader {
                Text(
                    text = "Header",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h3,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Gray)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)
                )
            }
            items(List(20) { "List item $it" }) {
                Text(
                    text = it,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .background(Color.Gray)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp),
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not exactly the same behavior. On the presentation we can notice that it's just a list with padded first item + top bar behavior.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired layout, you can use a Box composable to layer your components. Place an ImageView as the background within the Box, and then use a Spacer in front of it within a LazyColumn. This setup allows the Spacer to serve as the visible area boundary within the LazyColumn.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Box {
        // Background Image
        Spacer(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .height(300.dp)
                .background(Color.Green)
        )

        Column {
            // Header
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(50.dp)
                    .border(1.dp, Color.Black)
            )
            LazyColumn {
                item {
                    Spacer(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth()
                            .height(250.dp)
                    )
                }
                items(100) {
                    Text(text = "????????", Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Color.Gray))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```